# How to effectively cache/perssit Spark RDD join result

Tags: apache-spark, join, rdd

What am I trying to do:

- read large Terabyte size RDD
- filter it using broadcast variable, it'll reduce it to few gigabytes
- join filtered RDD with another RDD which few gigabytes too
- persist join result and reuse multiple times

Expectation:

- join executed once
- join result persisted
- join result reused several times w/o recomputation

IRL:

- join recomputed several times.
- half of entire job runtime spent on re-computing same thing several times.

My presudo-code

```scala
val nonPartitioned = sparkContext.readData("path")
val terabyteSizeRDD = nonPartitioned
.keyBy(_.joinKey)
.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(nonPartitioned.getNumPartitions))

//filters down to few Gigabytes
val filteredTerabyteSizeRDD = terabyteSizeDataset.mapPartitions(filterAndMapPartitionFunc, preservesPartitioning = true)

val (joined, count) = {
      val result = filteredTerabyteSizeRDD
        .leftOuterJoin(anotherFewGbRDD, filteredTerabyteSizeRDD.partitioner.get)
        .map(mapJoinRecordFunc)
      result.persist()
      result -> result.count()
}
```

DAG says that join is executed several times

- first time
- another time for `.count()` I don't know how to trigger persist is another way
- three more times since code uses `joined` three times to create another RDDs.

How can I align expectation and reality?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache or persist data in spark with `df.cache()` or `df.persist()`. If you are using `persist` you have further options then using `cache`. If you are using `persist` without an argument its just like a simple `cache()`[see here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) . Why dont you cache your `filteredTerabyteSizeRDD`? It should fit in memory if its just a few GB? If it doesnt fit in memory, you could try`filteredTerabyteSizeRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`.
Hope I could answer your question.